# Crystal reports multiple tables summary wrong table

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report, expression

I have been trying to write a report that will use multiple tables to create a stock report to include orders from one table for usage, stock items from another table and then the amount of stock items not yet invoiced to give a free stock position.

My structure is as follows, I have created the report from the main stock file to make sure that all stock items are included in the report, I have then linked the orders table to show how many orders of this item the customer has had in the past.  Here is where my problem came in, I have introduced a third table that contains temporary information that will affect the free stock until it has been invoiced.  I have created a summary field on this table and it is counting the orders table rather than the temporary table even through I have selected the temporary table in the summary field wizard.

I have tried adjusting the linking in the database expert but this doesn't seem to resolve the problem, does anyone know an easy way to do this with either an SQL expression field as I think this would be the easiest if the summary isn't working as expected.

Thanks

Comment: sql expression is similar to a function. create a function to be able to use this feat

Comment: I have just done some further inspection on the table and it seems that the values are multiplying by each other, so if there is 4 in the temporary table and 10 in the orders table it is showing 40 in the report information. not sure why this is happening.

Comment: to better understand your issue please post your schema thanks and sql version

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve the problem after hours of attempts so I thought I would share my findings with the community, pass it forward.

My issue was that linking three or more table together caused the summary fields to multiply together automatically, all I needed them to do was to return the summary separate but couldn't provide this information due to the problem mentioned and so summary on two different fields on two different tables returned the same value.

I realised that the sub reports were showing the correct information so I have created a sub report as a single field in the group header to display just the summary field calculations that I need, it is working fine and parameters are requesting fine and filtering without any issues.

So probably not the recommended way to resolve the issue but got me there in the end and I can finally call it a night.

Thanks